# Parse.com iOS SDK error - "Exception occurred: Unable to save a PFObject with a relation to a cycle."

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a PFObject instance using the iOS SDK, but when calling the save method I get the following error and my app crashes:

"Exception occurred: Unable to save a PFObject with a relation to a cycle."

Is it possible to get more detailed information about what this means, or which part of the PFObject is causing it?

The object in question is a rather complicated object graph, and I've been trying to debug the problem for hours without any luck.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I finally found out the root cause for the problem.

In different places of the object graph for the PFObject I was trying to save, there were several different PFObject representations of another object. For one of these instances, the objectId was not set. After fixing that, the whole PFObject graph was saved without problems.

Still not sure what the "relation to a cycle" error message meant in this case, so an explanation for this is still appreciated.

This is not the first time I stumble into very generic error message from the Parse SDK, so I'm really hoping for Parse.com to improve the detail level of error messages for the future. Just knowing the type of the violating object would have saved me hours of debugging in this case.

Comment: Can you post the offending code as well? I've seen similar errors, but I need a bit of guidance to help :)

Comment: Very generic and misleading message. I had the issue and like you it was just that one of the PFObject I was saving was not set.